# SQL Group Data Issue

Tags: sql, grouping

I'm trying to retrieve data from from a table such as:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
aaaa   bbbb   cccc   oooo   eric   date1
aasa   bcbb   ccfc   ooho   Samm   date2
aaaa   bbbb   cccc   oooo   eric   date3
aaaa   bbbb   cccc   oooo   Samm   date4
aaaa   bbbb   cccc   oooo   eric   date5
```

I would like to pull the latest date which is eric, as well as everything that belongs to Eric Not Samm.

```
aaaa   bbbb   cccc   oooo   eric   date5
aaaa   bbbb   cccc   oooo   eric   date3
aaaa   bbbb   cccc   oooo   eric   date1
```

Thanks for any help?

Comment: SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE col5 = 'eric' ORDER by col6 DESC; ?

Comment: I wish it was that easy for me. This is a view I'm creating and we only want the latest data? such as:                                                                       Select col1,   col2,   col3,   col4,   col5,   col6
  FROM table a
WHERE     (col6=
                          (SELECT     MAX(col6)  AS Expr1
                            FROM  table a AS b
                            WHERE      (a.[col6] = [b.col6])) WHich would be eric, but it only give me that last row. Thanks

Comment: @larry . . . Can yo better explain why Kuchi's answer doesn't work for you?  It seems like the right answer to your question to me.

Comment: Please describe in the question exactly what you have and what you want. It's hard to guess what you're aiming for....

Comment: We will have no idea whose name is in col5. Just want the view to always present the latest group of data. Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from tbl
where col5 in (select col5 from tbl where col6 = (select max(col6) from tbl))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question here... You want to first filter the query by "col5" and then sort it descending by the dates in "col6"?

In that case, the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col5 = 'eric' ORDER BY col6 DESC
```

Or, do you want to just pull the first row with the latest date (regardless of who it belongs to), then followed by all the rows belonging to eric? In that case, it will be (depending on RDMS, below is T-SQL for SQL Server)

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl ORDER BY col6 DESC UNION SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col5 = 'eric'
```

### Edit

I think I understand. You want to show the latest row, and then show all the other rows in the table which belong to *that user* (who's update is the latest).

Try this (again, meant for T-SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col5 = (SELECT TOP 1 col5 FROM tbl ORDER BY col6 DESC) ORDER BY col6 DESC
```

Or for MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col5 = (SELECT col5 FROM tbl ORDER BY col6 DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY col6 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t 
    JOIN (SELECT t2.col5, MAX(col6) as date FROM Table t2 GROUP BY t2.col5) as x 
    ON x.col5 = t.col5
```